# Using JOOQ with Kotlin Gradle DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jooq

I am trying to set up JOOQ code generation in Gradle using the Kotlin DSL, but am getting the error "Annotation class cannot be instantiated" when I run the generator task. What am I missing?

Here's the build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*
import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("java-library")
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.6")
        classpath("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.5")
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.jooq:jooq:3.16.6")
    compileOnly("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.6")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.5")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

// Set the following system properties to enable JOOQ to connect to the DB
// -Djooq.codegen.jdbc.user
// -Djooq.codegen.jdbc.password
//
tasks.create("generate") {
    GenerationTool.generate(Configuration()
            .withJdbc(Jdbc()
                    .withDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
                    .withUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"))
            .withGenerator(Generator()
                    .withDatabase(Database().withInputSchema("public"))
                    .withGenerate(Generate())
                    .withTarget(Target()
                            .withPackageName("com.example.db")
                            .withDirectory("src/generated/jooq"))))
}
```

And here is the stacktrace:

```
ScriptCompilationException(errors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Annotation class cannot be instantiated, location=/Users/foo/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-12544449971161496170.tmp/build.gradle.kts (51:33)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: withPackageName, location=/Users/foo/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-12544449971161496170.tmp/build.gradle.kts (52:30))])
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:187)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptToDirectory(KotlinCompiler.kt:148)
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.execution.ResidualProgramCompiler$compileScript$1.invoke(ResidualProgramCompiler.kt:708)
    [snipped 100+ lines]
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
```

Comment: What's the complete stack trace?

Comment: I've edited the question to add stacktrace. It happens when trying to instantiate Target. Perhaps Target instantiates an Annotation when it is constructed, which works in Java but not in Kotlin?

Comment: My first guess would be there's another `Target`, which happens to be an annotation. Check if you're using the correct Target class.

Comment: @Jorn: I agree, @Rob, can you try adding an explicit `import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Target`? That class isn't special, e.g. compared to `Generate` or `Database`, or the others in that package

Answer (score 4):

The issue was due to the class Target being shadowed by an annotation. The fix was to add an explicit import: `import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Target`

All credit to @Jorn and @Lukas Eder for the fix.